# print B5 on A4 then crop

Tags: crop

I printing my thesis and I have written it in B5 format by

```
\usepackage[b5paper,left=3.5cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,top=3cm,twoside]{geometry}
\special{papersize=176mm,250mm}
```

I want to print it on A4 then cut to B5 using crop guidelines can any one help me please

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [`zwpagelayout`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zwpagelayout) and/or the [`crop`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/crop) packages. They are able to put crop marks on your hardcopy.

Answer (score 6):

This is already possible with `geometry`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  layout=b5paper,
  left=3.5cm,
  right=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  top=3cm,
  twoside,
  showcrop
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\author{A. Uthor}
\title{A paper}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

[image]